# Why my antlr lexer java class is "code too large"?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

This is the lexer in Antlr (sorry for a long file):

```
lexer grammar SqlServerDialectLexer;
/* T-SQL words */
AND: 'AND';
BIGINT: 'BIGINT';
BIT: 'BIT';
CASE: 'CASE';
CHAR: 'CHAR';
COUNT: 'COUNT';
CREATE: 'CREATE';
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
DATETIME: 'DATETIME';
DECLARE: 'DECLARE';
ELSE: 'ELSE';
END: 'END';
FLOAT: 'FLOAT';
FROM: 'FROM';
GO: 'GO';
IMAGE: 'IMAGE';
INNER: 'INNER';
INSERT: 'INSERT';
INT: 'INT';
INTO: 'INTO';
IS: 'IS';
JOIN: 'JOIN';
NOT: 'NOT';
NULL: 'NULL';
NUMERIC: 'NUMERIC';
NVARCHAR: 'NVARCHAR';
ON: 'ON';
OR: 'OR';
SELECT: 'SELECT';
SET: 'SET';
SMALLINT: 'SMALLINT';
TABLE: 'TABLE';
THEN: 'THEN';
TINYINT: 'TINYINT';
UPDATE: 'UPDATE';
USE: 'USE';
VALUES: 'VALUES';
VARCHAR: 'VARCHAR';
WHEN: 'WHEN';
WHERE: 'WHERE';

QUOTE: '\'' { textMode = !textMode; };
QUOTED: {textMode}?=> ~('\'')*;

EQUALS: '=';
NOT_EQUALS: '!=';
SEMICOLON: ';';
COMMA: ',';
OPEN: '(';
CLOSE: ')';
VARIABLE: '@' NAME;
NAME:
    ( LETTER | '#' | '_' ) ( LETTER | NUMBER | '#' | '_' | '.' )*
    ;
NUMBER: DIGIT+;

fragment LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
SPACE
    :
    ( ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' )+
    { skip(); }
    ;
```

JDK 1.6 says `code too large` and can't compile it. Why and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I wouldn't say this is a big grammar, and there must be a reason why it doesn't produce reasonably sized code.

I think the problem is directly related to this rule:

```
QUOTED: {textMode}?=> ~('\'')*;
```

Is there any particular reason why you want the QUOTED part as a separate token, rather than leaving it combined with the quote, as Bart also put it in his grammar? This would also make the `textMode` variable obsolete.

Dropping the QUOTE and replacing QUOTED with

```
QUOTED: '\'' (~'\'')* '\'';
```

most probably will solve the problem, even without splitting the grammar.

Comment: I tried it and it does make a difference (using ANTLR 3.3 and Java 1.6.0_21). The generated Java will be reduced from 300KB to 60KB.

Comment: yes apologies, you're right. I tested it yesterday because I was surprised that the "code too large" error was already produces with that amount of keywords. My test from yesterday appears to have been wrong.

Comment: @Bart, never mind. The compile failure is caused by the 5000 lines in method DFA5.specialStateTransition, which isn't even generated in case QUOTED is organised as suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Divide your grammar into several [composite grammars](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars). Be careful what you place where. For example, you don't want to place the `NAME` rule in you top-grammar and keywords into an imported grammar: the `NAME` would "overwrite" the keywords from being matched.

This works:

### A.g

```
lexer grammar A;

SELECT: 'SELECT';
SET: 'SET';
SMALLINT: 'SMALLINT';
TABLE: 'TABLE';
THEN: 'THEN';
TINYINT: 'TINYINT';
UPDATE: 'UPDATE';
USE: 'USE';
VALUES: 'VALUES';
VARCHAR: 'VARCHAR';
WHEN: 'WHEN';
WHERE: 'WHERE';

QUOTED: '\'' ('\'\'' | ~'\'')* '\'';

EQUALS: '=';
NOT_EQUALS: '!=';
SEMICOLON: ';';
COMMA: ',';
OPEN: '(';
CLOSE: ')';
VARIABLE: '@' NAME;
NAME:
    ( LETTER | '#' | '_' ) ( LETTER | NUMBER | '#' | '_' | '.' )*
    ;
NUMBER: DIGIT+;

fragment LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
SPACE
    :
    ( ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' )+
    { skip(); }
    ;
```

### SqlServerDialectLexer.g

```
lexer grammar SqlServerDialectLexer;

import A;

AND: 'AND';
BIGINT: 'BIGINT';
BIT: 'BIT';
CASE: 'CASE';
CHAR: 'CHAR';
COUNT: 'COUNT';
CREATE: 'CREATE';
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
DATETIME: 'DATETIME';
DECLARE: 'DECLARE';
ELSE: 'ELSE';
END: 'END';
FLOAT: 'FLOAT';
FROM: 'FROM';
GO: 'GO';
IMAGE: 'IMAGE';
INNER: 'INNER';
INSERT: 'INSERT';
INT: 'INT';
INTO: 'INTO';
IS: 'IS';
JOIN: 'JOIN';
NOT: 'NOT';
NULL: 'NULL';
NUMERIC: 'NUMERIC';
NVARCHAR: 'NVARCHAR';
ON: 'ON';
OR: 'OR';
```

And it compiles fine:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool SqlServerDialectLexer.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
```

As you can see, invoking the `org.antlr.Tool` on your "top-lexer" is enough: ANTLR automatically generates classes for the imported grammar(s). If you have more grammars to import, do it like this:

```
import A, B, C;
```

### EDIT

Gunther is correct: changing the `QUOTED` rule is enough. I'll leave my answer though, because when you're going to add more keywords, or add quite a few parser rules (inevitable with SQL grammars), you'll most probably stumble upon the "code too large" error again. In that case, you can use my proposed solution.

If you're going to accept an answer, please accept Gunther's.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't suppose you can further break that down into separate files with import statements?

Apparently someone [wrote a post-processor](http://dermotoneill.blogspot.com/2009/07/antlr3-can-generate-very-large-java.html) to split things up automatically, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Although it's possible to handle this through an Ant task, it's so much more hassle than using ANTLR's built-in [composite grammar](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars) feature.