# The code of method specialStateTransition(int, IntStream) is exceeding the 65535 bytes

Tags: java, antlr

I have a pretty big grammar I don't want to break it into multiple smaller grammars. But The generated Lexer file is giving the following error:

```
The code of method specialStateTransition(int, IntStream) is exceeding the 65535 bytes
```

I am using ANTLR-3.2. Please tell me how to remove this compiler error.

Thanks

Preeti

Answer (score 4):

Method `specialStateTransition` is not always generated. It may be related to some tokens that share common prefixes with other tokens.

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283980/why-my-antlr-lexer-java-class-is-code-too-large/6292057#6292057) for a case where `specialStateTransition` completely vanished by reformulating just one such token.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently and managed to fix it by changing the options for the Antlr code generation tool..

```
C: java org.antlr.Tool –Xmaxinlinedfastates [a number less than 60] grammar.g
```

Using this option forces the code generator to create a table of DFA states rather than many nested `if` statements

Answer (score 1):

You can't: you will have to refactor your code. The limit is inherent to Java class files.

From [Section 4.10 (Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine) of the VM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659):

> The amount of code per non-native, non-abstract method is limited to
>   65536 bytes by the sizes of the indices in the exception_table of the
>   Code attribute (§4.7.3), in the LineNumberTable attribute (§4.7.8),
>   and in the LocalVariableTable attribute (§4.7.9).